# SSH run commands from local file and also pass local env variables

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I need to run SSH on Linux and execute commands from a local file into the remote machine. This is working fine, but I also need to pass local environment variables to the remote machine, so the commands can use the values.

Here is the command I'm running:

```
ssh -i ${SSH_PRIV_KEY} ${SSH_USER}@${IP} < setup.sh
```

I have a bunch of environment variables set and when the remote machine runs the commands in `setup.sh` file it needs be able to use the env vars from the local machine.

I tried many things, this but solutions from other threads like this don't work correctly:

```
myVar='4.0.23'
export $myVar
ssh -i ${SSH_PRIV_KEY} ${SSH_USER}@${IP} myVar=myVar < setup.sh
```

Only thing I can come up with is to append the start of the file and hardcode the values there before executing ssh, but if possible I would like to find a cleaner solution because I want this to be reusable and the only thing that changes for me between runs is the env vars.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but also note that `export $myVar` expands to `export 4.0.23`; you probably want to `export myVar`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this code to get the env vars I need to be stored in a file, then combine the files into one and pass that to the ssh as command:

```
envvars="
envvar='$envvar'
envvar2='$envvar2'

"
echo $envvars > envfile
cat envfile setup.sh > finalScript
cat $()
ssh -i ${SSH_PRIV_KEY} ${SSH_USER}@${IP} < finalScript
```